# XML file to other schema based XML file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

is it possible to rewrite XML file according to other schema XSD using c# ?

this is XML file

[image: this is XML file]

this is the current schema XSD file
[image: current schema XSD file]

and this is the new schema same everything but changed node names

[image: new schema]

so how to get a new XML from the old one based on the new XSD using c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> shipTo = doc.Descendants("shipto").ToList();

            foreach (XElement ship in shipTo)
            {
                ship.Element("name").ReplaceWith(new XElement("FullName", (string)ship.Element("name")));
                ship.Element("address").ReplaceWith(new XElement("FirstAddress", (string)ship.Element("address")));
                ship.Element("city").ReplaceWith(new XElement("homeTown", (string)ship.Element("city")));
                ship.Element("country").ReplaceWith(new XElement("HomeLand", (string)ship.Element("country")));

            }

        }

    }

}
```